# Sisteminha de busca com tabelas relacionadas mysql

Tags: mysql

Como podem ver na imagem abaixo, eu tenho a tabela Imóveis (mysql) que se relaciona com as tabelas Tipo, Bairro e Cidade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu preciso é o seguinte:

Tem um campo de texto para efetuar uma busca simples e pode ser digitado qualquer coisa. Suponhamos um usuário digite "São Bernardo do Campo", o sistema vai procurar nas tabelas Tipo, Bairros e Cidades até encontrar na coluna "nome" a palavra digitada e caso encontre, pega o ID e faz um loop comparando com o respectivo ID na tabela Imóveis e retorna todas as ocorrencias encontradas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de fazer com INNER JOIN, más eu estou tendo dificuldades para entender.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você vai ter que linkar todas as tabelas com o inner join.
Depois você tem que ver onde irá buscar 'campos'... 
Seria algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM `imoveis` AS `i`
INNER JOIN `tipo` AS `t` ON `i`.`tipo_id` = `t`.`tipo_id`
INNER JOIN `cidades` AS `c` ON `i`.`cidade_id` = `c`.`cidade_id`
INNER JOIN `bairros` AS `b` ON `i`.`bairro_id` = `b`.`bairro_id`
```

Isso faz as ligações das tabelas pelas respectivas chaves estrangeiras, após isso irá ter que fazer onde buscar...

```
WHERE `b`.`bairro_nome` = ? OR `c`.`cidade_nome` = ? OR `t`.`tipo_nome` = ?
```

Pronto, agora você tem sua query string, é claro que assim irá voltar todos os campos da tabela, antes você deve fazer o SELECT correto de quais campos irá querer ter o retorno.

> Obs: antes de postar uma pergunta tente ler sobre o assunto, estude
>   mais, isso é uma coisa simples de se fazer, iria conseguir em poucas
>   horas procurando na internet.

Comment: Mano, funcionou certinho.... valeu mesmo.